# Android Java How to make half screen keyboard and done in the edit text at the same time?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to make an EditText that its keyboard fills half screen in Landscape mode but also to have the done available at the same time since I have more than one EditText in my layout.

How can I use

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```

and

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

at the same time!!!

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ommabdelhafiz.amathmess.MainActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">











            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/first_1st"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="×"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/first_2nd"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="="
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="3"
                    android:hint="                "
                    android:id="@+id/first_ans"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>








                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/first_true_ans"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/first_false_ans"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Check"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:onClick="check1st"
                    android:id="@+id/first_btn"/>

            </LinearLayout>






            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="49"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/second_1st"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="÷"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/second_2nd"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="="
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2"
                    android:hint="                "
                    android:id="@+id/second_ans"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>









                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/second_true_ans"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/second_false_ans"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Check"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:onClick="check2nd"
                    android:id="@+id/second_btn"/>







            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="711"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/third_1st"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="×"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/third_2nd"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="="
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="4"
                    android:hint="                "
                    android:id="@+id/third_ans"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>








                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/third_true_ans"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/third_false_ans"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Check"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:onClick="check3rd"
                    android:id="@+id/third_btn"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="41.735"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/fourth_1st"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="23.836"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/fourth_2nd"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="="
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:hint="                "
                    android:maxLength="7"
                    android:id="@+id/fourth_ans"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>








                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/fourth_true_ans"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/fourth_false_ans"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Check"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:onClick="check4th"
                    android:id="@+id/fourth_btn"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="71.159"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/fifth_1st"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="14.704"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/fifth_2nd"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="="
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:maxLength="7"
                    android:hint="                "
                    android:id="@+id/fifth_ans"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>








                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/fifth_true_ans"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/fifth_false_ans"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Check"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:onClick="check5th"
                    android:id="@+id/fifth_btn"/>

            </LinearLayout>









        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried   android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionDone" , usually you can combine options with with a | (pipe)

Comment: Man Why don't you put this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine imeOptions with a | (pipe)

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionDone"
```